# How to load the same needed packages in multiple blogdown posts?

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

In some but not all posts of a blog made with blogdown I use highcharts to create interactive charts. For this, I need:

1. Include the necessary highcharts javascript sources in the relevant posts
2. Load the `highcharter` package (and also `magrittr`, as they work well together) in the relevant .Rmds

For the first point, a fairly elegant solution may be including a new param
`usehighcharts: true` in the params of the posts and then in the `header.html` partial use:

```
{{ if .Params.usehighcharts }}
 ... include the needed javascript ...
{{ end }}
```

But for the second point, I do not have an elegant solution, so what I do is manually include a chunk like so in the beginning of the relevant .Rmds, which I find error prone and not very elegant:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(highcharter)
  library(magrittr)
})
```
````

What would be a more elegant/best practice solution to this ?